# Azure CI pipeline ignored my botdetect.xml file

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, tfvc

I am using Azure CI pipeline and using the .NetCore build tasks template, today I noticed that the file botdetect.xml in my source control, and after project passes from CI/CD pipeline, specific .xml

Comment: check in your .csproj if the file is included with the project and should be copied to the output.

Comment: @MuneerNasir When you build you project locally with dotnet command line, is the .xml file in your build output?

Answer (score 2):

`dotnet publish` command publish the output of your .NET build, you need to make sure the `botdetect.xml` file exists in your build output, then it can be published to `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)` by running `dotnet publish --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)`, and publish the artifact by using Publish artifact task.

You could check your `.csproj` file to see whether the .xml file has been set to "Always Copy To Output Directory", it seems like:

```
<Compile Include="botdetect.xml">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</Compile>
```

Comment: Does your issue happen again?